# Download a File and Upload it with PHP and AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, ftp, download

I am developing a web application that uses JQuery AJAX and PHP to upload some data into my database.

One of the fields of the form to be submitted is an URL of a image (any address of the WEB). This image should be downloaded to my FTP server and then its new addrress would be inserted into the database.

How can I download an image from any URL and upload it to my FTP server?

**Form:**

```
<form id="form-id" method="post" action="insert.php" charset=utf-8">
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
    <input type="text" name="image-url" id="image-url">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#submit").live("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "insert.php",
        data : {
          'title': valueTitle,
          'image': valueImage
        },
        cache : false,
        success : function(html) {
        if (html == "success") {
            //...
        } else if (html == "ftp-error") {
            //...
        } else if (html == "sql-error") {
            //...
        }           
    }
    });     
});
```

**insert.php**

```
$title = $_REQUEST['title'];
$image = $_REQUEST['image'];

$imageInMyServer = downloadImageFromURLAndUploadFTP($image);
function downloadImageFromURLAndUploadFTP($image) {
    //that is what I want to know how to do.
}

//sql query with $title and $imageInMyServer
```

**Notes:**

- The file I want to download is not on my server. It is somewhere else in the Internet and I need to download it to my FTP server
- No. I cannot use the first external URL in my SQL Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a great example on [how to do FTP transfers in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ftp.examples-basic.php).  As far as downloading the file, you could use `wget` if you're on linux (using the `exec()` function).

```
exec('wget -q ' . $url . ' -0 /path/to/newfile');
```

Stealing a code snippet from that link I gave you, here is what your function might look like:

```
function downloadImageFromURLAndUploadFTP($image) {
    // in your case it would be some img extension like .jpg, .gif, or .png
    // you can check the extension of $image and use that if you want.
    $newFile = '/path/to/newfile.ext';
    exec('wget -q ' . $image . ' -0 ' . $newFile);

    if (file_exists($newFile)) {
        // set up connection and login
        $connect = ftp_connect($ftpServer); 
        $login   = ftp_login($connect, $ftpUser, $ftpPass); 

        // check connection
        if (!$connect || !$login) { 
            die('FTP connection has failed!'); 
        } else {
            echo "Connected to {$ftpServer}, for user {$ftpUser}";
        }

        // upload the file
        $fileNameOnFTPServer = 'whateverYouWantToNameIt.ext'; // arbitrary extension
        $upload = ftp_put($connect, $fileNameOnFTPServer, $newFile, FTP_BINARY); 

        // check upload status
        if (!$upload) { 
            echo "FTP upload has failed!";
        } else {
            echo "Uploaded {$image} to {$ftpServer} as {$fileNameOnFTPServer}";
        }

        ftp_close($connect);
    }
}
```

**Note:** Sometimes `file_exists()` doesn't behave the way we intended when the path *begins* with `/`.  For example `/path/to/file` might exist but `file_exists()` will think it doesn't unless you remove the beginning "/". One way to get around that is to check it like this:

```
file_exists(substr($newFile, 1))
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution if you do not have exec privileges is to use curl to grab the image, or you could use `file_get_contents()`, there are many ways, its just personal preference.

Ive put together what your script may look like, im sure you can improve it.

**insert.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['image']) && isset($_POST['title'])){
    if(substr($_POST['image'],0,4)=='http'){
        $image = curlgetimage($_POST['image']);
        $info = pathinfo($_POST['image']);
        if(isset($info['extension']) && ($info['extension']=='gif' || $info['extension']=='png' || $info['extension']=='jpg')){
            $path='./temp/'.md5($_POST['image']).'.'.$info['extension'];
            file_put_contents($path,$image);
            if(ftp_put_image($path)===true){
                //Do your database stuff, remember to escape..
                unlink($path);
                echo 'Success';
            }else{
                echo 'ftp-fail';
            }
        }else{
            echo'File type not allowed';
        }
    }else{
        echo'Must start with http://';
    }
}else{
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
}


function ftp_put_image($file){
    if(!file_exists($file)){return false;}
    $fp = fopen($file, 'r');
    $conn_id = ftp_connect('ftp.yourhost.com'); //change
    $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id,'username','password'); //change
    $return=(ftp_fput($conn_id, $file, $fp, FTP_BINARY))?true:false;
    ftp_close($conn_id);
    fclose($fp);
    return $return;
}

function curlgetimage($url) {
    $header[] = 'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg';
    $header[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';
    $header[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'YourSpiderBot/0.01 (Bla Bla Robot; http://www.example.com; spider@example.com)'); //change
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    $return = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $return;
}
?>
```

Comment: What should I put on the curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'YourSpiderBot/0.01 (Bla Bla Robot; http://www.example.com; spider@example.com)'); ?
Anything that uses my domain or do I have to use specific values?

Comment: The file is never being downloaded... So i am getting the FTP error file does not exist.
I don't know if it is not being downloaded by curlgetimage($url) or it is not being put by file_put_contents($path,$image)

Comment: @rlc First off you can put anything as the useragent, its polite to show yourself as a scrapper/bot but you could also masquerade as a normal browser. I did test this script with a form instead of the ` header('Location: http://www.example.com/');` maybe your form/jquery is the prob not sure, also check you have curl enabled on your server, I know xammp is not enabled by default(just need to uncomment a line) but 99% of webhosts are enabled.